# VSCode creates "Microsoft/TypeScript" folders in my home directory after each start

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't want to see this trash in my home location! How can I change the path?

[image: screenshot]

**UPD:** I found a temporary (not a perfect) solution:

- In settings.json add `"typescript.tsdk": "/usr/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib"`
- In /usr/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js find string "Microsoft/TypeScript" and change it.

This solution will work only until next update :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue, it will be fixed in TS 2.2, you could disable the folder recreation until the new version of TS or VSCode will appear with this setting:

```
  "typescript.disableAutomaticTypeAcquisition": true
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/16318

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/17336